# mongodb - see the data

Tags: mongodb

I have an asterisk server with cdr and mongodb. the data is in /data/db and its ok but i want to see it in plain "text". not local.0 and so on..
how can i mount it maybe to a directory and see the files(mp3) from the cdr.

Thanks.

example of a server that i have and working ok:

root@mdb-rec-pri:/mnt/as_cdr/2013/01/01/01# ls

20130101-010711-4078-014639052763220.mp3  20130101-011908-4067-012971505877422.mp3  20130101-012508-4078-012971505584293.mp3  20130101-013240-4067-012971503569841.mp3  20130101-014028-4078-012971502368075.mp3
20130101-010713-4067-012971506499222.mp3  20130101-012001-4078-012971506915939.mp3  20130101-012536-4067-012971509112891.mp3  20130101-013250-4078-012971554011234.mp3

i have a second server that the db is on, and i want to see that data from that server in my primary server.

Comment: Plain text? Why don't you just write code to extract what you need?

Comment: What is cdr? I can't figure out what you mean by context.

Comment: Do you mean that you're saving the asterisks cdr's into mongoDB?